# Проблемы со слайдером и функцией prepend()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такая дилемма. Сделал слайдер, всё работает хорошо кроме одного момента: если нажимать на одну картинку 2 раза то большая версия исчезает совсем. Я полагаю что prepend() не срабатывает.

```js
$('.laast img').each(function(){
            var oldImg = $(this).attr('src'); 
            var ext= /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
            var newImg = oldImg.replace(ext,'_q$1');
            var newI= $('<img src="'+newImg+'">');
        $(this).click(function(){
            newI.hide();
         $('.big').prepend(newI);
            newI.fadeIn(1000);
            $('.big img:last').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="laast">
    <p>Заголовок заголовок</p>
    <img src="image/small/blue.jpg" alt=""> 
    <img src="image/small/green.jpg" alt=""> 
    <img src="image/small/orange.jpg" alt=""> 
    <img src="image/small/purple.jpg" alt=""> 
    <img src="image/small/red.jpg" alt=""> 
    <img src="image/small/slide1.jpg" alt=""> 
    <div class="big">
        <img src="image/small/blue_q.jpg" alt="" class="q2">
        
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Вам не нужен цикл. Перепишите код, используя `$('.laast  > img').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Цикл чтоб заранее путь загрузить для кеша чтоб не зависала

Comment: "на одну картинку 2 раза то большая версия исчезает" - потому что `newI` и `$('.big img:last')` соответствуют одному и тому же DOM-элементу.

Comment: @Igor Но ведь когда срабатывает prepend() он уже не ".big img:last"  там по идее должно быть 2 эемента

Comment: см. ответ ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prepend`, конечно, срабатывает.

"на одну картинку 2 раза то большая версия исчезает" - потому что `newI` и `$('.big img:last')` соответствуют одному и тому же DOM-элементу. То есть новый DOM-элемент не добавляется, он уже существует внутри jQuery-евской обертки, и Ваш код добавляет его к его же собственному родителю.

```
if (newI[0] != $('.big img:last')[0]) {
  $('.big img:last').fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

или

```
$('.big img:last').not(newI).fadeOut(1000,function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я условный оператор буду использовать. Помогло

Comment: Но цикл я применил не зря? чтоб заранее путь загрузить для картинки и не зависало ничего.