# Расположить текст относительно картинки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, текст

Есть код

```
<h1><a href="site.ru" id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt=""> Здесь должен быть текст</a></h1>
```

При использовании данного кода, получается вот так

[image: Вертикальное расположение текста]

(Треугольничек это картинка-логотип, текст это текст логотипа).

В чем вопрос: *Как текст сделать ровно по центру картинки справа. Внутренний перфекционист негодует.*

Comment: Слева логотип, справа текст, нужно сделать так что бы текст располагался относительно изображения по вертикале по центру(думаю ясно выразился). По поводу системы, я имел ввиду вообще весь html, по моему мнению, способ расположения текста более чем глуп. При вставке изображения напротив текста, текст падает на нижнюю часть картинки. Это видно из вырезки скриншота. (Треугольничек - логотип. "КАААААК???" - текст к логотипу).

Comment: lline-height? https://habrahabr.ru/company/netcracker/blog/277433/

Comment: Либо в вопросе показываете код как вы пытаетесь сделать, либо вопрос ни о чем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способов выравнять логотип, относительно названия компании бесконечное множество и ограничены они лишь нашей фантазией.

Для того чтобы точно ответить на вопрос я использовал именно ту вёрстку, которую предоставил автор, однако если выйти за её рамки, то возможно изначальной проблемы даже не было.

Однако, хочу заметить, что несмотря на то, что я использовал вёрстку автора вопроса, результат у него может отличаться за счёт наложения ранее им написаных стилей.

Для того чтобы этого не происходило, рекомендую автору вопроса указывать классы и идентификаторы объектам и тщательнее подходить к выбору селекторов при составлении правил CSS.

**Отрицательный margin**

Указываем отрицательный отступ снизу, тем самым смещаемся "под строку", на которой расположено изображение.

```html
<h1>
    <a href="site.ru" id="logo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvEH3.png" alt=""/> 
        Здесь должен быть текст
    </a>
</h1>
<style>
    h1 img {
        margin-bottom: -30px;
    }
</style>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**вертикальное выравнивание изображения**

Указываем, что изображение должно выравниваться посередине относительно строки.

```html
<h1>
    <a href="site.ru" id="logo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvEH3.png" alt=""/> 
        Здесь должен быть текст
    </a>
</h1>
<style>
    h1 img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**смещение лого с помощью transform**

тут посложнее.
похожий на первый вариант, только смещаемся относительно строки с помощью модного свойства transform

```html
<h1>
    <a href="site.ru" id="logo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvEH3.png" alt=""/> 
        Здесь должен быть текст
    </a>
</h1>
<style>
    h1 img {
        transform: translateY(39%);
    }
</style>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**позиционирование+растягивание**

тут ещё сложнее и без допинга не все смогут разобраться
указываем, что изображение абсолютно позиционировано относительно родительского объекта
указывая нулевое расстояние до границ родительского объекта растягиваем его на 100% родительской высоты
после указания автоматического отступа сверху и снизу, изображение позиционируется по средней линии родительского объекта
т.к. изображение позиционируется абсолютно, то оно заезжает на текст
чтобы пофиксить добавим внутренний отступ родительскому объекту и внешний изображению
отступ должен быть равен ширине картинки

```html
<h1>
    <a href="site.ru" id="logo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvEH3.png" alt=""/> 
        Здесь должен быть текст
    </a>
</h1>
<style>
    h1 a {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 200px;
    }
    h1 img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }
</style>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Продолжать можно бесконечно, однако изощрённость ответов будет увеличиваться.
Опять же подчеркну, что если изменить вёрстку, то отделаться можно было бы и более простыми приёмами.
Суть не в этом

---

Если описанные выше способы не будут Вам подходить, это значит, что проблема лежит за пределами указанного Вами кода и там Вы сделали то, чего делать не стоило. 
И вероятность этого достаточно высока, т.к. Вы уже жаловались, что ответы данные Вам ранее Вам не подходят, несмотря на то, что в изолированной среде они работают отлично. Поэтому я не стал увлекаться с "бесконечным списком" и решил подождать реакцию автора вопроса.
Проверяйте и отписывайтесь по результату

Если ответ не подходит, но Вы предоставите достаточное количество исходных данных, Мы всегда Вам поможем.

Comment: Вам не то что спасибо, вам просто благодарность вселенского масштаба! Вы мне очень помогли, все сделал по способу "позиционирование+растягивание". Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @Evgeniy, я рад что всё получилось :)

Comment: Добавьте способ с flexbox, как по мне он самый идеальный в таких случаях.

Comment: @l2banners, спасибо за комментарий. Как появится время - обязательно добавлю.

Answer (score 6):

> КАААААК???

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.smiles2k.net/big_smiles/big_smiles_74.gif" alt="">А вот так.
```

Comment: А что то знаете, не работает. Очевидно я уже пробовал таким образом, и наверное по этому я обратился за помощью. 
http://s010.radikal.ru/i313/1701/96/4a0a06e77e79.jpg

Comment: @Evgeniy, пример в сниппете определенно работает. В то же время. неизвестно для какой разметки сделал указанный скриншот, поэтому неизвестно что и как ты пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

`float: left` убери с картинки...

Comment: И опять мимо. Вот код http://s014.radikal.ru/i328/1701/e6/151e381c52b1.jpg 
Как видим сейчас по логике текст должен и правда падать на нижнюю часть картинки. Если пытаемся привязать текст в css и вставить vertical-align, то ничего не происходит. Я извиняюсь за излишнюю эмоциональность, но даже не представляете, что сверстав бОльшую часть лендинга, меня победила картиночка размером в 70 пикселей. Это непередаваемое чувство...

Comment: @Evgeniy Вы принципиально будете код картинками вставлять?

Comment: А как ещё? Как то по другому?

Comment: @Evgeniy, в текстовом виде в теле вопроса.

Comment: @Evgeniy, посмотрите как оформляют вопросы: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617484/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-prepend

Comment: @Evgeniy, у меня как у отвечающего есть выбор: потратить кучу сил и времени для выяснения деталей, для набора примера кода подходящего для Вас или же ответить на вопрос, в котором всё это уже есть. Как Вы думаете, что я выберу?.. Мы все очень хотим Вам помочь, но для этого нужно чтобы Вы изложили всё в вопросе.

Comment: Сейчас исправлю все.

Comment: @Evgeniy, отлично. Я добавил ответ.

Comment: @Evgeniy и где в вашем вопросе css который вы применяете? Вы так и не поняли как надо оформлять вопрос

Comment: Да отстаньте же вы пожалуйста с оформлением вопроса, я больше времени потеряю для оформления вопросов нежели для разрешения проблемы. Надоели уже. Ответ уже дали, можете идти дальше бродить. Спасибо за ответ...

Comment: @Evgeniy, не стоит так с Алексеем. Он знает, что говорит. Если бы Вы изначально оформили вопрос нормально, то Вы бы получили ответ на сутки раньше. Это приличное время. Более того смысл данного сообщества не только в том чтобы помогать непосредственно авторам вопросов, но и в том, чтобы данным опытом воспользовались другие пользователи, у которых возникли похожие проблемы. Ежедневно сотни и тысячи людей находят ответы в уже заданных кем-то ранее вопросов. И будут заходить на Ваш. И сообществу важно, чтобы каждый вопрос был полным и хорошо оформленным.

Comment: @Evgeniy, мы уверены что Ваш следющий опыт на stackoverflow будет гораздо приятнее и удачнее! :)